# Media is not importing correctly when importing using import script

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I need to create one import script along with media folder which will create necessary banners in db.

I have created a zip file which contains **importscript.impex** file and **media** folder with required jsp files.

When I am importing zip file though import script, it starts complaining about media path issue.

Sample Impex -

```
INSERT_UPDATE Media ; $contentCV[unique=true] ; code[unique=true]                                 ; mediaFormat(qualifier) ; realfilename   ; @media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator] ; mime[default='image/jpeg'] ; folder(qualifier)[default='images'] ; altText         
                    ;                         ; /images/banners/site/Default/abc.jpg              ; Default                ; abc.jpg        ; /media/abc.jpg        ;                            ;                                     ; ""
```

How can i give my folder media reference in script ?

Comment: You can check this question answer for accessing files in zip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761185/hybris-how-to-import-media-which-is-in-the-zip-file-in-impex

Comment: @mkysoft : I want to create an independent Zip file which anyone can download and import using import script irrespective of where they have downloaded zip.

Comment: You need to upload zip file to server before impex script. There is no screen for uploading files to server folder. May be you can give permission to user for uploading zip files via ftp. Then they can run impex script. On the other hand, jsp file upload very hard. If hybris running with complied war/ear file, impossible. Also you cannot access master and slave files same time for uploading jsp files.  You can create your own upload screen and process zip file in java code for creating media and banner context.

Comment: Consider de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.DefaultMediaDataHandler or hybris wiki on information how to import medias using impex. However I think that your case is not covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try using only media name (abc.jpg) without any path in the import script and upload your media zip folder while running your import script.

---

Go to HMC/Backoffice import tools then upload **importsript.impex** or ***.csv** which has the data to import

Import file looks like:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Media ; &Item ; @media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator] ; catalog(id)[allownull=true] ; catalogVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true,allownull=true] ; code[unique=true,allownull=true]   ; folder(qualifier)[forceWrite=true] ; mediaContainer(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),qualifier) ; mediaFormat(qualifier) ; realFileName                          
                    ; Item0 ; 8797897457694.gif                                                          ; testContentCatalog          ; testContentCatalog:Staged                                       ; ContentPageModel__function_preview ; root                               ;                                                               ;                        ; ContentPageModel__function_preview.gif
```

[image]

Now in the next screen, you can see the option to upload the associated media folder. There you need to upload a zip file containing the media with the same name you have mentioned in the script.

[image]

Click on Start to trigger the job and check it's status from cronJob.

Comment: Yes I did the same. Thanks